# Numeric Enum is considered as a string in type comparison

Tags: typescript, enums

While trying to do a comparison between a numeric enum, I noticed an error where the enum value is converted to a string type. Is that an expected behavior?

```js
enum Test {
    a = 0,
    b = 1
}

console.log(Test.a === Test[0]);
// ^ This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'Test' and 'string' have no overlap.(2367)
```

TypeScript version: **v4.6.4**

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=1&pln=21&pc=33#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM+AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL+gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBBCcQQ0MwAUVWDEQC0gADVHBQGNJ3KAALygABEAAkYNAMOB4GRonzFBTBPB3AERcwABS0+mM9ysygc9wASmCKhwzQ8ZC8iHFzmB7BoXzcZmY7AYzEg-Fg0HUiQ58D0Ii8fLpDKZgj5SWxfPADlQAHJhAA5SASPlBFQAeS+ZHegmdWkgR1QjgUrmkeFATjNOmGWH0KAQiGhwkuNok4uiIgMHGxCyYrA4PCCihR7EQ3n0NAA3ooSiVxLyAAy8CeT6Q80AARkUAF9yY1ZfLFUqcCOAtPubyD1SANozgC6OoA3EA)

Comment: `Test[0]` is using the [reverse mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings) to get `"a"`.  Why are you trying to compare them like that?  Either you want `console.log(Test.a === 0)` or `console.log("a" === Test[0])`, but what you're doing is checking a key against a value.  Does that make sense and should I write up an answer?  Or am I missing something about your question?

Comment: @jcalz oh you are right, I thought it would be comparing two values, but it is indeed different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a confusion about what `Test[0]` is.  Numeric `enum` members in TypeScript get a [reverse mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings), where indexing into the enum object with an enum *value* gives you back the corresponding enum *key*.

So in

```
enum Test {
    a = 0,
    b = 1
}
```

you have `Test.a === 0` and therefore `Test[0] === "a"`.  And since `Test.b === 1`, then `Test[1] === "b"`.  By comparing `Test.a` to `Test[0]`, you are comparing a number to a string, and is indeed considered a TypeScript error to make such a comparison.

So you shouldn't write

```
console.log(Test.a === Test[0]); // error, different types.  Outputs false
```

But instead possibly one of these:

```
console.log("a" === Test[0]); // okay, Outputs true
console.log(Test.a === 0); // okay, Outputs true
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKsDOAXKBvAUFTUCGUC8UADADQZYBG+UAjGgL5poDGA9iPCwDbAB0nLAcwAUcJD1x5JsBIgDahALoBKANxQA9OqgAzbJ3jBmbDtz6CRM8fimFVGrYgBOYQ63Zde-YQCJs36wSicop2mlBOLkA)